# SSL Handshake failed (IceWarp mail server)

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

We have an SMTP client custom software that has worked perfectly until recently with our SMTP server. We changed nothing in the settings both of the client and the server, but the client software started to fail to send emails several days ago. This is the log from our mail server:

```
1.2.3.4  [080C] 10:01:05 Connected, local IP=1.2.3.4:587
1.2.3.4  [080C] 10:01:05 >>> 220 mail.zzz ESMTP IceWarp 11.4.6.0 x64; Tue, 21 Mar 2017 10:01:05 +0100
1.2.3.4  [080C] 10:01:05 <<< ehlo TMAIL
1.2.3.4  [080C] 10:01:05 >>> 250-mail.zzz Hello TMAIL [1.2.3.4], pleased to meet you.
                                    250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                    250-SIZE 52428800
                                    250-EXPN
                                    250-ETRN
                                    250-ATRN
                                    250-DSN
                                    250-CHECKPOINT
                                    250-8BITMIME
                                    250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 GSSAPI
                                    250-STARTTLS
                                    250
1.2.3.4  [080C] 10:01:05 <<< starttls
1.2.3.4  [080C] 10:01:05 >>> 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
1.2.3.4  [080C] 10:01:05 SSL: Handshake with client failed on 1.2.3.4:5871
                                    <<< (SSLv2/v3 read client hello B ,2,0) 01030100570000002000001600001300000a0000660000070000050000040000150000120000090700c00500800300800100800800800600400000650000640000630000620000610000600000140000110000080000060000030400800200801b3d416e (128)
                                    >>> (SSLv3 read client hello C ,0,256) 1503010002
                                    >>> (SSLv3 read client hello C ,769,21) 0228
1.2.3.4  [080C] 10:01:05 *** <> <> 0 0 00:00:00 INCOMPLETE-SESSION
1.2.3.4  [080C] 10:01:05 Disconnected
```

The server is IceWarp 11.4.6.0 on port 587 running on Windows Server 2008 R2

The same client sends emails through public servers such as smtp.live.com without issues via port 25 using STARTTLS.
In the same time Thunderbird sends emails via our server without issues too, with STARTTLS enabled.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Did you find the solution?
I am having the same problem.

Comment: @GuillermoHernández the problem was that our SMTP clinet software was using old ssl ciphers which are no longer supported by the server